# django error in auth user model ValueError: Related model 'pcpartpicker.user' cannot be resolved

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am using django authentication and it keeps giving me this error when I run the migrate cmd `ValueError: Related model 'pcpartpicker.user' cannot be resolved`

This is my model :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Functions:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect , render
from .error import error
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from ..models import User

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            return error("102", "Invalid username or password", request)
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("/")

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["Cpassword"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return error("203", "passwords do not match", request)
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return error('102', "email in user", request)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, "register.html")
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} 

{% block body %} 
<section class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:h-screen lg:py-0">
        <div class="w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:border md:mt-0 sm:max-w-md xl:p-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <div class="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
                <h1 class="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-2xl dark:text-white">
                    Sign in to your account
                </h1>

                <form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action="/login" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div>
                        <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Your email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="name" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="your" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" required="">
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-full text-white bg-blue-600 mb-2 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">Sign in</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} 

{% block body %} 
<section class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:h-screen lg:py-0">
        <div class="w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:border md:mt-0 sm:max-w-md xl:p-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <div class="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
                <h1 class="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-2xl dark:text-white">
                    Create your account
                </h1>
                <form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action="/register" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div>
                        <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Your email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="name" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="youremail@example.com" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" required="">
                    </div>                    
                    <div>
                        <label for="Cpassword" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="Cpassword" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" required="">
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-full text-white bg-blue-600 mb-2 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">Sign in</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

At first it would not let me run makemigrations either but then I added this line to my settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'pcpartpicker.User'
```

Now it lets me make the migrations but does not migrate them

my app is in installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pcpartpicker'
]
```